# Co-Authors Plus: How do I get all authors with a query?

Tags: php, functions

I've recently installed the Co-Authors Plus plugin and am trying to get all the authors from a post within a post loop. However for some reason when I use `get_queried_object()`, there is only one author listed not multiple.

Is there a way to get all the authors from a post using `WP_Query` or some other manner?

Comment: Do you mean all authors?

Comment: No, I mean all the authors from that one post, so if I add 2 users to the post e.g. Admin and myself, I want to be able to get both admin and myself in another wordpress loop e.g. archive page with a WP_Query

Comment: @GufranHasan Please stop misusing code markup. Thank you.

Comment: @fuxia, Okay thanks, I will take care it next time :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Co-Authors Plus plugin. By default, it will show the original author of the post.

You’ll need to edit theme files with the code responsible for showing the author name for posts. This could be `single.php, content.php,` or a template tag in your theme’s `functions.php` file.

`the_author_posts_link()` and you will need to replace it with the following code snippet.

```
if ( function_exists( 'coauthors_posts_links' ) ) {
    coauthors_posts_links();
} else {
    the_author_posts_link();
}
```

[Reference](https://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/allow-multiple-authors-to-be-associated-with-a-post-in-wordpress/)

You can use the following code to get co-authors.

```
<?php $coauthors = get_coauthors(); ?>
<?php foreach( $coauthors as $coauthor ): ?>
<center><div class="authbio">
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/<?php echo $coauthor->user_firstname; ?>.jpg" alt="" class="alignleft"/>
<?php $userdata = get_userdata( $coauthor->ID ); ?>
<?php if ( $userdata->user_description ) echo $userdata->user_description; ?>
</div></center>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not trying to show the authors in the content. As I've stated, I want to get the all of the authors from one page. So if I add 2 authors to the about-us page, I want to be able to WP_Query those 2 authors, currently I only get 1 author back, which is the author that is at the top of the list.

Comment: Please see this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32805028/co-authors-plus-wordpress-plugin-list-all-the-authors-for-same-post